# NSNumberFormatter rounding to negative zero

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnumberformatter

I'm using `NSNumberFormatter` to format float values as integer strings, i.e. omitting the fractional part. I find it odd, that numbers in range `(-0.5, 0)` <sup>*open interval</sup> end up as `-0`. As this value will be displayed to the user, I think that negative zero is not appropriate. I have experimented with various combinations of `numberStyle` and `roundingMode` without success.

Is there a way to configure the `NSNumberFormatter` to output them as `0`, or do I have to resort to manual correction for that range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do correct this myself. I am using the NSNumberFormatter to display temperature with default `numberStyle` — `NSNumberFormatterNoStyle` which rounds the numbers to the whole integer, `roundingMode` set to `NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp`. In the end I did intercept the values in problematic range and round it myself:

```
- (NSString *)temperature:(NSNumber *)temperature
{
    float f = [temperature floatValue];
    if (f < 0 && f > -0.5)
        temperature = [NSNumber numberWithLong:lround(f)];

    return [self.temperatureFormatter stringFromNumber:temperature];
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is you're fixing this on the calling site when you should implement this locally in a number formatter extension method. Something like, `changeToZeroIfNegativeZero`. This is similar to the extension method `nilIfEmpty` on the `String` class.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to configure it to do that.

In "10.4 mode", NSNumberFormatter basically just wraps CFNumberFormatter (although it's not a direct toll-free-bridged wrapping). You can look at the list of Number Formatter Property Keys and it's pretty clear that there's nothing that will do what you want. (It may be possible in "10.0" mode; it would take a bit of trial and error to find out. But I doubt you want to use that.)

So pre-rounding (as Justin Boo suggests) is probably your best option.

You could, of course, post-process instead. Exactly what you want to do probably depends on whether you want to also render -0.00 as 0.00, what you want to happen for localizations that don't use "-0", etc. The simplest case would be as simple as this:

```
@interface NSNumberFormatter (NegativeZero)
- (NSString *)stringFromNumberNoNegativeZero:(NSNumber *)number;
@end

@implementation NSNumberFormatter (NegativeZero)
- (NSString *)stringFromNumberNoNegativeZero:(NSNumber *)number {
  NSString *s = [self stringFromNumber:number];
  if ([s isEqualToString:@"-0"]) return @"0";
  return s;
}
@end
```

But if you want anything more complicated, it'll get more complicated.

Comment: OK. I went with intercepting the value in problematic range and rounding it myself: `float f = [number floatValue]; if (f < 0 && f > -0.5) number = [NSNumber numberWithLong:lround(f)];`

Comment: Note that string manipulation as shown here does not properly handle all locale. There are other symbols used for `0`, and potentially also different symbols for negative values. You are better off rounding the number in numeric form and letting the number formatter do its job.

Comment: @Palimondo: The answer already says that "pre-rounding… is probably your best option", and that even if you do decide to post-process, "Exactly what you want to do probably depends on… what you want to happen for localizations that don't use '-0'", so that comment doesn't add any new info.

Comment: It does. I wanted to emphasize the potential problem for developers with little experience with internationalization.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this String extension in Swift which solves the problem:

```
extension String {
    static func stringFromDouble(_ doubleValue: Double, minimumIntegerDigits: Int = 1, maximumIntegerDigits: Int = 42, minimumFractionDigits: Int = 0, maximumFractionDigits: Int = 2, roundingMode: NumberFormatter.RoundingMode = .halfUp) -> String {
        // Create number formatter
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = minimumIntegerDigits
        formatter.maximumIntegerDigits = maximumIntegerDigits
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = minimumFractionDigits
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = maximumFractionDigits
        formatter.roundingMode = roundingMode
        
        // Get string
        var string = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: doubleValue))
        
        // Avoid "-0" which can happen with very small negative numbers
        if string == "-0" {
            string = "0"
        }
        
        return string ?? ""
    }
}
```