# NumberFormatter incorrect behaviour for small negative numbers in currency mode

Tags: swift, nsnumberformatter

When using a `NumberFormatter` and setting `numberStyle` to `.currency`, the formatter rounds all numbers to 2 decimal places, as expected. However, for small negative numbers, whose value rounded to 2 decimal places is 0 (number >= -0.005), the output string contains the negative sign and hence becomes `-$0.00` instead of `$0.00`.

Is there are way to change this behaviour just by toggling some properties of the `NumberFormatter` instead of having to use a workaround? At the moment I am rounding the value to 2 decimal places myself, checking if the output is `-0` and acting accordingly. However, it would be great if the `NumberFormatter` could be set up such that it doesn't distinguish `-0` and `0`.

Below code shows the issue and my current workaround (feel free to test in a playground) - I know that the `Locale` should be set based on the `currencySymbol`, but this is just code for showcasing the issue, not production code):

```
public class CurrencyFormatter {

    private let formatter: NumberFormatter

    public init(locale: Locale = Locale.current) {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = locale
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        self.formatter = formatter
    }

    // Adds currency symbol and returns a string e.g. input 1 output "£1"
    public func formatWithCurrencySymbol(value: Decimal, currencyCode: String) -> String? {
        formatter.currencyCode = currencyCode

        // Workaround for cases when the currency behaviour rounds small negative values (<0.0051) to -0.00, where we don't want to have a - sign
        var value = value
        if value < 0 {
            let roundedValue = round(Double(truncating: value as NSDecimalNumber) * 100.0)
            if roundedValue == 0 && roundedValue.sign == .minus {
                value = 0
            }
        }

        return formatter.string(for: value)
    }

    public func formatWithCurrencySymbolNoWorkaround(value: Decimal, currencyCode: String) -> String? {
        formatter.currencyCode = currencyCode
        return formatter.string(for: value)
    }
}

let formatter = CurrencyFormatter()

formatter.formatWithCurrencySymbol(value: 0.01, currencyCode: "USD") // "$0.01"
formatter.formatWithCurrencySymbol(value: -0.001, currencyCode: "EUR") // "€0.00"
formatter.formatWithCurrencySymbol(value: -0.0002, currencyCode: "EUR") // "€0.00"
formatter.formatWithCurrencySymbol(value: -0.01, currencyCode: "EUR") // "-€0.01"

formatter.formatWithCurrencySymbol(value: 0.01, currencyCode: "USD") // "$0.01"
formatter.formatWithCurrencySymbol(value: -0.001, currencyCode: "EUR") // "-€0.00"
formatter.formatWithCurrencySymbol(value: -0.0002, currencyCode: "EUR") // "-€0.00"
formatter.formatWithCurrencySymbol(value: -0.01, currencyCode: "EUR") // "-€0.01"
formatter.formatWithCurrencySymbolNoWorkaround(value: -0.005, currencyCode: "EUR") // "-€0.00"
```

Comment: Related: [NSNumberFormatter rounding to negative zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10837926/1630618)

Comment: @vacawama thanks, it seems there indeed isn't a proper configuration solution

Comment: It appears there isn't, which is a shame because many would find negative zero to be a nonsensical thing to display.  This leaves everyone figuring out a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You could add simple logic to check if the value is less than -0.01 and, if so, return the absolute value.

`return value < -0.01 ? formatter.string(for: abs(value)) : formatter.string(for: value)`

Comment: As you can see in the question, I already found a workaround before asking, but I wasn't looking for a workaround, I was looking for a proper solution using a property of `NumberFormatter` to get the desired behaviour (which sadly doesn't seem to exist). As explained in the sentence: _"Is there are way to change this behaviour just by toggling some properties of the NumberFormatter instead of having to use a workaround?"_

Comment: Yeah, sorry about having to use a whole answer to convey my thoughts. I would have added this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation points yet to comment directly. I was just offering a potentially simpler workaround. It would be nice if Apple would add a property that allows us to dictate this behavior.